# Mockito: Attach Answer to every method of arbitrary Object instance

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

I have the following situation:

I want to attach an `Answer` to every method call of a specific class instance. So for example with the class

```
public class Example {
    public int example1() { /* */ }
    public int example2(Object a) { /* */ }
    public int example3(Object a, Integer b) { /* */ }
    public int example4(int a) { /* */ }
}
```

I want to do the following

```
public Example attachToExample(Example ex) {
    Example spy = Mockito.spy(ex);
    Answer<Object> answer = /* */;
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).example1();
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).example2(any());
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).example3(any(), any());
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).example4(anyInt());
    return spy;
}
```

This works but what I would like to do is generalize this to not just `Example` instances but arbitrary Objects.

So what I would like to do is

```
public Object attachToExample(Object o) {
    Object spy = Mockito.spy(o);
    Answer<Object> answer = /* */;
    for(Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
        /* skipping methods that cannot be mocked (equals/hashCode/final/..) */

        doAnswer(answer).when(spy)./* Method m with according arguments */;
    }
    return spy;
}
```

What I would need to do for that is construct argument matchers `any`/`anyInt`/.. depending on the amount of parameters of each method and their types (primitive/non primitive). Ideally I would create a list of arguments like this:

```
Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
ArrayList<Object> args = new ArrayList<>();
for (Class<?> param : params) {
    if ("int".equals(param.toString())) {
        args.add(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt());
    } else { // Cases for other primitive types left out.
        args.add(ArgumentMatchers.any()); // Found non primitive. We can use 'any()'
    }
}
            
try {
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).getClass().getMethod(m.getName(), m.getParameterTypes())
            .invoke(spy, args.toArray());
} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This does not work as using argument matchers outside of stubbing is not supported but I hope that this makes clear what I want to do.

Is there any way to make this work or is there a different way of archiving what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found a way to do what I want:

While the array of arguments cannot be constructed before the `invoke` call we can do so with an external method call like so:

```java
try {
    doAnswer(answer).when(spy).getClass().getMethod(m.getName(), m.getParameterTypes())
            .invoke(spy, constructArguments(m));
} catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where `constructArguments` is the following:

```
private static Object[] getArgumentMatcher(Method m) {
    Class<?>[] types = m.getParameterTypes();

    Object[] res = new Object[types.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < types.length; ++i) {
        if (types[i].isPrimitive()) {
            // For primitives we need to specify the type explicitly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            res[i] = any(types[i]);
        } else {
            res[i] = any();
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```